# Unable to retrieve results from a large table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am issuing a very simple query against a table with 15,000,000 rows. I am experiencing erratic behavior regarding `rownum` limits.

For example, whe following query

```
select * from (select * from my_table order by id) where rownum < 2000000
```

works without trouble, as well as this one

```
select * from (select * from my_table order by id) where rownum between 1 and 15
```

but this one never completes

```
select * from (select * from my_table order by id) where rownum between 2 and 15
```

I can't explain this behavior: when the lower limit is 0, the upper limit can be huge without any trouble, but when the lower limit is just two, it never completes. It is also strange that there is no in-between: it either returns almost immediately, or never completes.

The table is indexed on the `id` column and it's an `asc`-sorted index; otherwise I assume that finding even just the first record would require a full table sort.

Where should I investigate to get this fixed?

My databes is `Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production`

Comment: This is iterating over every row in `my_table` - when you get the first row from `my_table`, the `rownum` is 1. This fails the condition `between 2 and 15`. Record is skipped, and you get next one - again, with `rownum` = 1. This is also skipped and so on. You need additional subquery to be able to restrict the rownum range between two values, like this: `select * from (select * from (select * from my_table order by id) where rownum <= upper_limit) where rownum >= lower_limit;` Check this: [pagination queries](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2007/07-jan/o17asktom-093877.html)

Comment: Thanks, @PrzemyslawKruglej. So I did fail on something trivial here.

Comment: I do think so, yes. When the `rownum` condition can be met, and you have index on the column by which you are ordering, you are getting the results fast, because the rows that meet the condition are found fast. When the `rownum` condition is not met, the database has to go over the whole table before it, in the end, will get no results (because of the reason in my previous comment). Can you try the solution with additional subquery that I proposed?

Comment: @PrzemyslawKruglej I've checked it and unfortunately it is again taking forever (tried with lower=10 and upper=20).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT /*+ FIRST_ROWS */ myquery.*, ROWNUM rnum
    FROM (
        SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY id
    ) myquery
    WHERE ROWNUM <= 15
) WHERE rnum >= 2;
```

Comment: This is it, thanks. In the meantime I have come to the same expression.

Answer (score 2):

As @prezmyslawKruglej started to explain, a condition `where rownum > 1` will never return any records. It is [described in detail by Tom Kyte](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html).

I suggest you use the `row_number()` function instead, something like

```
select ... from (
  select ..., row_number() over (order by whatever) as rn from ...
) where rn between 10 and 20
```

Comment: It had a syntax error (missing FROM) so I corrected to `select * from (
  select mycolumn, row_number() over (order by id) as rn from mytable
) where rn between 10 and 20`. However, this also fails to complete.

Comment: Good explanation for the behaviour (+1 for the link), however I would advise against using `row_number()` with a large table, as this will need to read and sort the entire table, whereas rownum can use an index to read only the first N rows.

Comment: @vincent Agree, that's probably what is behind the "fails to complete" thing. However, in real life it's not often that you need to page through millions of rows, so there would be other criteria restricting what is being selected.